# Protect test/beta site running in azure

Tags: azure

We're developing a new website running in azure. We are currently developing against the local azure dev environment. But now we need to publish and test the site in the real Azure world. But we would like to run in a "closed" environment, where only know users have access, as the site should not go live yet. Any suggestions to accomplish this?

/Rasmus

Comment: This is such a good question. I suggest an IP address restriction. You'll need a static IP address. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Azure has something called 'staging mode', see this post: http://sevans.info/2010/10/10/windows-azure-staging-model/

It's very powerful, and exactly what you need as far as I can see.

Comment: But still my site /url is public. Does the staging mode provides some authentication by itself? Our site uses ACS with social providers, when "running". But for staging I want complete control over access

Comment: No, staging does not offer you the protection you are after

Comment: Staging deployments have a guid as the first part of their name (<guid>.cloudapp.net), so while it's theoretically possible for someone to find your beta site, it's highly unlikely.

Comment: Use staging as Leon suggested.  Implement security on top of your app, even its just forms auth.

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the endpoints of your instance configuration, so there will be no forwarding through the load balancer. After that you could use the Remote Desktop to log into your azure instance and test your web application.

Comment: Not a good idea at all. first removing endpoint will change application dynamics and removing instance from LB is very easy. please see my positing.

Comment: You are right. Seems to be the easier way to run the ps command with the help of the rdp session. Good hint!

Answer (score 0):

Above suggestions are great and I would also like to add two more in this list as well:

1. Using production deployment and having a dummy index/default page with directory browsing disabled (already set as default) So when someone come you your site there is nothing they will see. And as there is no directory browsing so they can not guess the page*.aspx to visit your site. This will keep your production site running and you can test it from outside.
2. Removing your instance form Load Balancer while keeping your instance healthy. This will require you to test the Azure Application by RDP to your instance and then launch internally. If you wish to do so here is the [Powershell based trick.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2012/01/27/windows-azure-troubleshooting-taking-specific-windows-azure-instance-offline.aspx)

Comment: 1. is sort of security through obscurity though. The internet still knows your app is there. They'll get some pages through brute forcing, unless you rate limit, like this: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/confirming-dynamic-ip-address-restrictions-in-windows-azure-web-sites/

Answer (score 0):

You could restrict the IP addresses that are allowed to access your app if you have a static IP address. As per this link: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/ip-and-domain-restrictions-for-windows-azure-web-sites/

Developers can use IP and Domain Restrictions to control the set of IP addresses, and address ranges, that are either allowed or denied access to their websites. With Windows Azure Web Sites developers can enable/disable the feature, as well as customize its behavior, using web.config files located in their website.

Here's the code:

```
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false" denyAction="NotFound">
      <add allowed="true" ipAddress="123.456.0.0" subnetMask="255.255.0.0"/>
    </ipSecurity>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```